# When login button is pressed, how to just compare email and password to the ones in the database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to Android Studios and I have created a register database with columns: first name, second name, last name, email, password. When users login, they enter their email and password. How do I only check two columns from SQLite database?

I have tried

```
Boolean res = db.checkUser(user, pwd);
```

but that only stops the emulator from working. I have also tried

```
Boolean res = db.checkUser(null, null, null, user, pwd);
```

which allows the emulator to work, but stops logging in from working.

```
/* When the login button is pressed, check if the username and password 
are in the system*/
mButtonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String user = mTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String pwd = mTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        Boolean res = db.checkUser(null, null, null, user, pwd);
        if(res == true)
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Successfully 
            Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         else
             Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Error", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My checkUser function is

```
public boolean checkUser(String email, String password){
    String[] column = {COL_1};
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String selection = COL_5 + "=?" + " and " + COL_6 + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = { email, password } ;
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,column,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if(count>0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: Just pass these two enough. `db.checkUser(user, pwd);`. Also show us your `checkUser` function.

Answer (score 1):

**checkUser** function should be something like this:

```
public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query("YOUR_DATABASE_TABLE_NAME", null, "EMAIL = ? AND " +
        " PASSWORD = ?", new String[]{email, password}, null, null, null, "LIMIT 1");
    try {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "checkUser: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now you can get what you want:

```
Boolean res = db.checkUser(user, pwd);
```

Although, passwords better keeping in hash, but this is for another question...

Answer (score 0):

you can try in this way:

```
if(user.equals(your db username) && pwd.equals(your db password)
    {
    //Login successful
    }else
    {
    //invalid credentials
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not really sure what to put in the brackets for (your db username) and (your db password).

Comment: the user name and password stored in the database

Comment: you can get those values using cursor.